# Update multiple rows following a pattern in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, design-patterns, field

I have many fields in a column with a name starting with field_t and I have to change them to field_c

Examples of renaming:

```
field_t_detail should be field_c_detail
field_t_title should be field_c_title
field_t_id should be field_c_id
...
```

Here is the UPDATE statement for changing the name of one of the fields:

```
UPDATE my_table SET name  = field_c_meta WHERE name LIKE 'field_t_meta';
```

How can I change all the fields that follow this pattern instead of doing it in a one by one basis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using the `REPLACE` function. Does it helps you?

```
 UPDATE my_table 
    SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`, '_t_', '_c_')
```

[REPLACE SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) 
[REPLACE SYNTAX](http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/database/mysql/find-replace.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can update several fields at the same time like this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET name = 'field_c_meta',
    name2 = 'field_c_meta',
    name3 = 'field_c_meta'
 WHERE name LIKE 'field_t%';
```

---

If you wnat to change only the name column it should be something like this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET name = 'field_c' + SUBSTRING(name, 7)
 WHERE name LIKE 'field_t%';
```

**This will update all `name from field_tSOMETHING to field_cSOMETHING`.**

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
name LIKE 'field_t%'
```

All names starting with `field_t` will be matched.